# NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am very new to android. I made an application with purely some activities through tutorials. Now I am trying to make some of these things in **fragments**.

I altered some of the code but I still got 1 error left. 
Its at the bottom at:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

The error is my topic title.

What is going wrong? How do I fix the error?

```
    public void showNotification(){

    String onderwerp = ("Herinnering");
    String name = ("Vergeet uw medicijnen niet in te nemen!");

    // Geluid notificatie
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    // Notificatie trigger
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

    // De notificatie
    Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(getActivity())

        .setContentTitle(onderwerp)
        .setContentText(name)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setSound(soundUri)

        .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotification.vibrate = new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500}; 
    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);

    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
}
```

Comment: There's no `NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER` as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Fragment` can access the `Activity`, you can access the `getSystemService()` from `getActivity()`

Java

```
NotificationManager notificationManager 
           = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Kotlin

```
val notificationManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

Because `Activity` inherits `getSystemService()` from `Context`.

Comment: Did not work, than notificationManager is undefined.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. I'll set answer to correct in 1 minute. (I am than allowed)

Answer (score 2):

`NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` is a constant of the `Context` class.

Try

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type HomeFragment

Comment: @user2883477 Try `getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: Did not work: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to NotificationManager

Comment: @user2883477 You have to do `(NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 2):

NOTIFICATION_SERVICE is not visible. Try using Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE; or

```
import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
```

Comment: As explained above, if you are inside a fragment, you can't call getSystemService(). getSystemService() is a Context method. A fragment isn't a context but its Activity is. An Activity is a Context so you need to get a reference to the fragment's activity first: notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

Or

notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: Did not work, I think. If I try those: notificationManager cannot be resolved to a variable.